# Doubt in Real and Complex Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, real-numbers

There are many theorems in linear algebra which hold for matrices which are members of $ ℂ^{n×n}$ but not for matrices which are members of $ \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$. But matrices with all entries as real numbers(i.e. members of $ \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$)  are also members of  $ ℂ^{n×n}$, so if a theorem holds for  $ ℂ^{n×n}$ it should hold for all of its elements,which also includes elements of  $ \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$. But that does not happen. Why?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a theorem?

Comment: @StephenDonovan     If A ∈ $ ℂ^{n×n}$ is a  normal matrix, then A is unitarily diagonalizable.(Spectral theorem for Normal Matrices).Note that it does not hold for matrices with all entries as real numbers

Comment: The definition of a normal matrix only makes sense if we are working in $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n},$ so I think it may not be that this does not hold for real-valued matrices, instead it may just be that the statement is only sensible when treating those real-valued matrices as complex-valued. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @StephenDonovan definition of normal matrix makes sense even if we are working with real matrices.

Comment: Yes but my point was it only makes sense if we're working in a space with complex-valued matrices. Otherwise the conjugate transpose doesn't make sense.

Comment: @StephenDonovan conjugate of a real number is the number itself(which makes sense). So conjugate transpose of a matrix with real numbers should also make sense.

Comment: Every real normal $n\times n$ matrix *is* unitarily diagonalizable, just not necessarily so over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: "diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$" and "diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$" are two different things. A normal matrix is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$, but not necessarily over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @coconutmercury Ok my apologies, I wasn't familiar with this definition of conjugate when working on $\mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some confusion here. Every theorem about $n\times n$ complex matrices is also valid for $n\times n$ real matrices, since $\Bbb C$ is an extension of $\Bbb R$. What happens is that not all such statements remain valid if we insist in working only with real numbers. For instance any $n\times n$ complex matrix has an eigenvalue, but it is not true that any $n\times n$ real matrix has a *real* eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks!This cleared my confusion

Comment: I'm glad I could help.